# Grab columns from multiple .csv files as sample for ANOVA in R?

Tags: r, bash, awk

I have a few .CSV files and want to perform an ANOVA test in R using the last column from each .CSV file as samples for the ANOVA.

To make an example, here's the first file:

```
E, Run1, Run2, ..., Runn, Mean
0, 1.48, 1.22, ..., 1.01, 1.24
1, 1.42, 1.12, ..., 1.00, 1.18
2, 1.11, 1.11, ..., 0.98, 1.07
3, 1.00, 0.98, ..., 0.90, 0.96
..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ...
```

And the second:

```
E, Run1, Run2, ..., Runn, Mean
0, 2.11, 2.00, ..., 1.98, 2.03
1, 2.00, 1.99, ..., 1.64, 1.88
2, 1.98, 1.90, ..., 1.60, 1.83
3, 1.90, 1.85, ..., 1.22, 1.66
..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ...
```

Declaratively, I want the final column of each file, and ignore the first row. So I might have `sample1 = [1.24, 1.18, 1.07, 0.96, ...]`, and `sample2 = [2.03, 1.88, 1.83, 1.66, ...]`. Then I can do an ANOVA using the two samples.

My example uses two files but if there's an approach that can do an arbitrary number of .CSV files and performs the ANOVA, that's preferable.

I'm not terribly familiar with R so any help is appreciated. I've tagged as `bash` and `awk` because I don't mind using those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be one way, with the data at hand:

```r
library(purrr)

data1 <- read.table(text=
"Epoch, Run 1, Run 2, Run 3, Mean
0, 1.48, 1.22, 1.01, 1.24
1, 1.42, 1.12, 1.00, 1.18
2, 1.11, 1.11, 0.98, 1.07
3, 1.00, 0.98, 0.90, 0.96
",header=TRUE, sep=",")

data2 <- read.table(text=
"Epoch, Run 1, Run 2, Run 3, Mean
0, 2.11, 2.00, 1.98, 2.03
1, 2.00, 1.99, 1.64, 1.88
2, 1.98, 1.90, 1.60, 1.83
3, 1.90, 1.85, 1.22, 1.66
",header=TRUE, sep=",")

list(data1, data2) %>%
    imap_dfr( ~ data.frame( sample=paste0("sample",.y), value=.x[,ncol(.x)] ) )  %>%
    lm( data=., value~sample ) %>% anova
```

Output:

```
> anova(lm(value~sample, data=d))
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: value
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
sample     1 1.08781 1.08781  56.424 0.0002881 ***
Residuals  6 0.11567 0.01928                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

To generalize across multiple files:

```r
library(purrr)
dir( "some/where/", pattern="\\.csv$", full.names=TRUE ) %>%
    map_df( ~ read.csv( .x ) %>% select(last_col()), .id="filename" ) %>%
    setnames( c("filenumber", "value" ) ) %>%
    lm( data=., value~. ) %>% anova
```